# Cannot assert the same fact in the memory

Tags: clips

In clips I have the following fact in the memory. and I want to regenerate it by some rule. When I regenerate it it does not add it to the facts. because all fields value are same. Any solution to this problem?

```
(objct (name food) (edible? yes) (isa Object))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic Programming Guide, section 13.4.4, Setting the Duplication Behavior of Facts. http://clipsrules.sourceforge.net/documentation/v630/bpg.pdf

```
CLIPS> (clear)
CLIPS> (deftemplate objct (slot name) (slot edible?) (slot isa))
CLIPS> (assert (objct (name food) (edible? yes) (isa Object)))
<Fact-1>
CLIPS> (assert (objct (name food) (edible? yes) (isa Object)))
FALSE
CLIPS> (facts)
f-0     (initial-fact)
f-1     (objct (name food) (edible? yes) (isa Object))
For a total of 2 facts.
CLIPS> (set-fact-duplication TRUE)
FALSE
CLIPS> (assert (objct (name food) (edible? yes) (isa Object)))
<Fact-2>
CLIPS> (facts)
f-0     (initial-fact)
f-1     (objct (name food) (edible? yes) (isa Object))
f-2     (objct (name food) (edible? yes) (isa Object))
For a total of 3 facts.
CLIPS>
```